# Discord bot python-writing in text files and logging

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I've been trying to log all the messages that my bot can see.
My code for logging does work, but it cancels out the other commands and now the other commands don't work. Any idea how to fix this?

My code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
import random
import sys
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.utils import get
from itertools import cycle
import datetime
import time
import random
from word import word_list

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    file1 = open("logs", "a")
    file1.write(f'{message.content}, {str(message.author)}')
    file1.write("\n")
    file1.close()

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")

client.run("bot token here")
```

Ignore some of the imports, they aren't important, they are for my other commands(I have around 800 lines of code and don't want to post it all here). I also have a file in my directory called "log". Wordlist isn't a problem either, its just something to help make a hangman game in discord.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `on_message()` function needs to enable the processing of commands. Enter `await client.process_commands(message)` as the last line in `on_message()`.

Comment: ohhh thanks so much! I thought i saw an error like that but it disappeared. Weird!